# D3 .js Select All pass variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to select all the elements which are having a specifiv value for the bound-by attribute
so on clicl of will be executing the below piece of code

and storing the value in a variable and then applying a transition effect

```
var bindingProp = d3.select(this).attr("bound-by");
var test = d3.selectAll(bindingProp);
test.transition().duration(1500).delay(000).attr("x", 35);
```

but the above code is not working any suggestions?

or is their a way in which i can use selectAll to select the elements having bound-by attribute or is it that select all accepts only classNames

the problem is that the bound-by is not static it will be determined on what element the user has clicked so i want to pass a variable to it that and that variable will contain my bound-by value which user has clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
var boundByVal = d3.select(this).attr("bound-by");
var el = d3.selectAll("[bound-by="+boundByVal+"]")
   .transition()
   .duration(1500)
   .delay(000)
   .attr("x", 35);
```

`d3.select("[bound-by=boundByVal]")` code will return element having `bound-by` attribute value set as boundByVal

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle[bound-by=name]");
console.log(circle.node());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle r="15" cx="25" cy="50" bound-by="name"></circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I the problem is that the boundByVal is not staic it will be determined on what element the user has clicked so i want to pass a varible to it that variable will contain my boundByVal which user has clicked so how can i pass a variable in  d3.select("[bound-by=boundByVal]")??